# Estimate Gas too big

Tags: web3js, gas, gas-limit, gas-estimate

Im trying to estimate the gas of this kind of tx to send to a contract

```
 var estimateGas = this.web3.eth.estimateGas({
  to: toContractAddress,
  gasPrice: this.web3.toHex(40000000000),
  nonce: 10,
  value: this.web3.toHex(forwardingValueInWei)
})
```

And I get as return this value: **4 712 388**
which is super big gas, while the MyEtherWallet estimate  **127 943**

are those estimations the same unit? 
Why is too big from web3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4,712,388 is the old block gas limit. This used to be the most gas you could send in a transaction. This probably means that your software is detecting an error condition. An error takes all available gas. Since you aren't specifying a limit to how much gas you want to send, this takes all the gas you could possibly send.

Comment: so should I add the gasLimit parameter with a lower than 4 712 388  inside of the estimateGas function?